# Using emoji's by typing colon generates smileys too early

Tags: microsoft-teams

When using Teams, I want to add emojis by using colons, ex. typing **":smile..."**
However, Teams is too quick to add a smiley, thinking that **":s"** what I want (which is not), i.e. I end up with not being able to get/use the emoji I want... See picture (I don't want the smiley which appear in the red square)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dft2.png)

Comment: Emojis are made by auto-correction of `:s`  (and `:smile:`). I could enter it only as `:s`+undo+`mile:`.

Comment: When you enter : smile in the compose box, you get an option to choose the type of smiley you want to add . Please see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmtRu.png).

Comment: @Gousia: I only get choises if the code is not alresdy converted to an emoji. Emoji's starting with ":s" for instance, turns automatically into an emoji.

Comment: @JoopEggen do you have any links with a list of those emojis following the `:emoji:` format ?

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham https://365trainingportal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Microsoft-Teams-Emoji-Shortcuts.pdf (I just searched for _teams emoji_ a moment ago)

Comment: I've found that if I type the letters fast enough (i.e. get the third letter in there quick), the `:s` in `:sm` doesn't autocorrect, and instead the emoji chooser pops up. However, just recently the collection of `:emoji:` have disappeared for me - not sure if this is a universal change or an instance-specific change.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parenthesis` instead of `colon` e.g.

> (nod)
> (smile)